# latex url not formatted

Tags: latex

I wrote the following expression in overleaf, however, when I compile it, the right hand side of the url spread out the right side of my document, it doesn't go to a second line. I am not sure what is the reason, as it works perfectly when I use a wiki url.

\url{https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca}. (something wrong)[image: see image here]

\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices}(works as desired)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{xurl}`. In case this does not help, please make a [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, thanks, it works, I used the ```\usepackage{hyperref}``` package, probably something not correct with this package?

Comment: Everything is fine with the `hyperref` package, it just has less possible break points than `xurl`. If you want line breaks at strange places, you just need the `xurl` package in addition, that's why it exists

Comment: Or simply use the short version of the url: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3869